# What's the probability of having 1 loser in a 5 way game of rock, paper, scissors?

Tags: probability

Me and my friends had a 5-way game of rock, paper, scissors recently and on the first go we had a single loser as 4 of us chose paper and the loser chose rock. What are the odds of this happening? Is it just as simple as 1/3 ^ 5? Because the odds of one person choosing one option doesn't affect the anyone else's choice and it doesn't make it any more or less likely. Also do you have to take into account that the loser has to choose the hand symbol that will lose to the 4 others? What's the maths behind it?

Comment: Almost as simple. You just need to consider all the possible situations in which there is only one loser, which is 3 (the element which lost) times 5 (the loser), and then divide 15 by the total number of possible situations, which is $3^5$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we look at the option 4x paper, 1x rock.

The probability of this calculates as follows:
We need 4 people to have paper, and one person to have rock; so far $\frac{1}{3}^5$.

*However*, there is five different possibilities here - every single person could be the unlucky one to have chosen the rock. Since, doing this sort of calculation, we are doing no more than counting possible outcomes, this means we have to multiply our result by $5$:

$P_1=5\cdot\frac{1}{3^5}=\frac{5}{3^5}\approx 0.02$

Again, we are not quite done just yet. So far we have the probability that we get a loser by rock. There's three different ways this scenario can happen, though, namely each of rock, paper and scissors, so we will finally have to multiply our probability by $3$:

$P=3\cdot\frac{5}{3^5}=\frac{5}{3^4}\approx 0.062$.

Phrased differently, if you really like playing rock, paper, scissors with 4 friends, then this will approximately occur in every 20th game or so. And once every 100 games you will be the unlucky loser. However, you will also win against everyone else every 100 games, and approximately every 10 games there will be some single person either winning or losing against all others.